GDM Select default user, skip user list
When you login you have to choose user from the list before entering password. I have only one user.  I want to boot straight into password prompt.

I think there is only one way which is to automate the click simulation which will be a bad idea. Even if you disable the user list on gdm, you have to enter username first and then password which you don't want rite.


Log in automatically:
You can change your settings so that you are automatically logged in
to your account when you start up your computer:
Open the Activities overview and start typing System.
Select Settings ▸ System from the results. This will open the System
panel.
Select Users to open the panel.
Press Unlock in the top right corner and type in your password when
prompted.
If it is a different user account that you want to log into
automatically, select the account under Other Users.
Switch the Automatic Login switch to on.
When you next start up your computer, you will be logged in
automatically. If you have this option enabled, you will not need to
type in your password to log in to your account which means that if
someone else starts up your computer, they will be able to access your
account and your personal data including your files and browser
history.

Ubuntu 24.04 » Help Ubuntu Desktop Guide » Settings » Users › Accounts » Log in automatically

No, I don't want to log in automatically. I still want to have password requirement.

you can install LightDM, it picks the user automatically and requires the password

Alright, it works as I asked. Shame the layout looks worse than gdm

you can change the background or the lightDM theme https://www.gnome-look.org/browse?cat=154&ord=latest
